# php contradictions with $_POST

Tags: php, array-key-exists

I have this program:

```
if (!isset($_POST['foo'])) doSomeThing1();
else {
    if (!array_key_exists('foo',$_POST)) doSomeThing2();
    else doSomeThing3();
}
```

but... the program flow goes to the 3d case, failing with the error: `undefined index 'foo' (in file.php, line xxx)`.

Could you explain, why?
Why `array_key_exists` returns `true` (which brings the script to the 3d case) but subsequently it is "undefined index"?

Comment: have you tried looking at your data with a `var_dump($_POST)`? that could help us debuggin, too. also - what's in file.php:xxx? the code throwing the error could be relevant to debugging the error, don't you think?

Comment: Please `print` your post value first, even you can use `var_dump()` to undestand more that what data is coming exactly and why it is not meeting any condition.

Comment: What is implied by `doSomeThing3()`?

Comment: Please let us know what you are expecting when there is 'foo' key in $_POST; When there is NO 'foo' key in $_POST etc

Comment: Thank's, have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!isset($_POST['foo'])) doSomeThing1();
else {
    if (!array_key_exists('foo',$_POST)) doSomeThing2();
    else doSomeThing3();
}
```

As per this code how it's working is...

`!isset($_POST['foo'])` ==> returns `true` and executes `dosomeThing1()` when there is NO `'foo'` key in `$_POST` array

if `$_POST` doesn't have any key it is checking `!array_key_exists('foo',$_POST)`

`array_key_exists('foo', $_POST)` checking whether `'foo'` key is there in `$_POST` array or not. `array_key_exists('foo', $_POST)` is same as `isset($_POST['foo'])` so it is always executing `doSomeThing3()` when there is no `'foo'` key in `$_POST` array.

Hope this explanation helps.